# How to solve probleme : "Too many attempts" in laravel 9 api

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm working on a login system in laravel but found this problem message:
**"message": "Too Many Attempts.",
"exception": "Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\ThrottleRequestsException",**

The code I'm using:

```
Route::post('auth/login', 'AuthController@login');
Route::post('reset-password', 'AuthController@sendPasswordResetLink');
Route::post('reset/password', 'AuthController@callResetPassword');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::get('auth/user', 'AuthController@user');
}
```

Comment: Presumably you guessed the login credentials wrong too many times. The solution is to get them right. It's unclear in what way this represents a problem or a programming question?

Comment: No, the credentials are not wrong, it worked for me before but I don't how this problem happened.

Comment: Somehow I doubt the system is lying to you. Ask yourself, what else has changed in the meantime? But if there _is_ an issue, we can't help you without a [mre] of it, and I don't think the code you've shown so far is really going to provide one.

Comment: P.S. are you entirely building your own login system or using one of the starter kits described at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authentication#laravels-built-in-browser-authentication-services ?

Comment: No, I'm using my own login system

Comment: Double-check your throttle in `config/auth.php`, make sure it's not set to a really low number. It should be set to at least 60

Comment: The rate limiter is usually based on using a cache so try clearing your cache and see how fast the problem appears again. There might be a problem with your code somewhere that repeats requests to the api too frequently (i.e. via ajax or something like that)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, I tried this commands and it worked:

```
php artisan cache:clear,
php artisan config:clear,
```